# Preposition for referring to a tool

Tags: prepositions

Is it ok to use *via* to refer to a tool (The camera in this context) or should I use *with* or some other conjunction

> Photo by John Doe **via** Canon EOS 60D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're writing a caption for a photograph. In that case I'd write:

> Photograph by John Doe **using a** Canon EOS 60D

Comment: An alternative might also be “with a”