# “via” vs. “through”

Tags: differences, prepositions, synonyms, latin

Could you please explain what the difference in usage is between *through* and *via*, which sounds like a Latinism?

Are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: To me "via" sounds more professional and educated. I also use via more often because sometimes I am not sure which preposition to use e.g. "with" or "through" so I use "via" instead ;). E.g. via our e-mail, via our phone.

Comment: [Related to, and probable dup of one or another of](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=via+is%3Aquestion): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/52980 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6195 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/59575 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8879

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are examples to be found where the words are not interchangeable. In normal speech you won't hear "he walked via the door" much...

Comment: @MrLister Yes, that’s right. There are indeed some occasions in which they are interchangeable, but many more in which they are not so. Any good dictionary will explain this.

Comment: Could you name one or two? Even with the OED (as seen in your answer), it seems to be you doing the explaining, and without total conviction ('one _perhaps might_ be able to make that swap').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Easily.  The citations given for OED sense 2 of *via* could be rewritten using *through* without any change in meaning.

Comment: I was referring to your statement  _Any good dictionary will explain this_. What you then proceed to do is 'deduce this' from dictionary material. Most dictionaries seem not to offer explanations; the AHDEL, in its occasional 'usage notes', is one that bucks the trend (I am glad to say).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using *via* as a preposition in English is of comparatively recent provenance. It has substantially fewer primary senses, and therefore available uses, than does *through*.  The OED gives only two main senses for *via* as a preposition, which I include here with a few of each one’s later citations:

> 1. By way of; by the route which passes through or over (a specified place).
>
>    - 1958 A. Sillitoe *Saturday Night & Sunday Morning* iv. 60 — Arthur and his father walked via the scullery into the living-room.
>    - 1959 M. Gilbert *Blood & Judgement* xiii. 138 — More··had come to the Police via the Lower Deck of the Royal Navy.
>    - 1981 G. Household *Summon Bright Water* iii. 149 — He led me to talk of my interest in ancient economies and thus, via agriculture in the Forest of Dean, eased the way to my impressions of Broom Lodge.
> 2. By means of, with the aid of.
>
>    - 1972 M. Kaye *Lively Game of Death* (1974) vii. 41 — Any deal··would have to be··concluded via contracts, attorneys, the whole *schmeer*.
>    - 1977 Rep. Comm. *Future of Broadcasting* iv. 30 — It would in theory be possible to provide five more services with national coverage via satellite.

Here are some examples of *through* (taken from the OED’s citation list for that preposition) where you **could not substitute** in *via* in its stead:

> - 1847 Tennyson **Princess** iv. 554 - Thy voice is heard thro’ rolling drums.
> - 1848 Thackeray *Van. Fair* xxxii, — George··was lying··dead, with a bullet through his heart.
> - 1852 R. S. Surtees *Sponge’s Sp. Tour* (1893) 85 — He was small and wiry, with legs that a pig could run through.
> - 1886 Ad. Sergeant *No Saint* I. vi. 105 — An old land surveyor··put him through a long catechism.
> - 1896 T. F. Tout *Edw. I*, iv. 80 — All through his reign, the Lusignans helped him in Gascony.
> - 1903 *Times* 14 Mar. 14/5 — The Oxonians showed good form through choppy water.
> - 1975 *Nature* 10 Apr. 501/2 — Nine recognised glaze types, ranging in colour from pale blue, through green, to yellow, brown and red.
> - 1981 L. Deighton *XPD* xliii. 342 - A··notice stating that deliveries were only accepted between eight and eleven Monday through Friday.
> - *Mod.* — There is a path through the wood.
> - *Mod.* — It has passed through many hands since then.

In contrast, in these examples from the same source, one perhaps might be able to make that swap:

> - 1852 Dickens *Bleak Ho.* viii, — Mrs. Pardiggle··had been regarding him through her spectacles.
> - 1885 *Act 48 & 49 Vict*. c. 53 §15 — Every notice··sent through the post in a prepaid registered letter.
> - 1894 J. J. Fowler *Adamnan Introd*. 56 — The southern Picts··embraced the truth through the preaching of St. Ninian.

So even though though there are a few places where you can use *via* or *through* — or else *via* and *by* — interchangeably as prepositions, there are many others where you cannot.

Finally, it should be noted that there are substantive, adjectival, and adverbial uses of both words, and that these non-prepositional uses are never interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to understand that "via" is used when you have to say "with" as a complement indicating an instrument (physical or abstract). In this case you should be allowed to switch it to "through", while if "through" has other meanings, you cannot substitute it with "via". This is what I grasp here.

Comment: @martina That’s one way to look at it, I suppose.

Answer (score 12):

tchrist's answer says it all about the definitions of these words.

On the matter of usage, I'm sorry to see **via** being used in place of **through** more and more. I put it down to a desire to appear educated and sophisticated, but it backfires, and comes across as pretentious or betrays a lack of care in using the language.

Via has a well established usage meaning to go from one geographical location to another *by way of* a third. That's how the Romans used it. More recently it was reserved for travel contexts and remains useful in this sense, for example a Northern line train (on the London Underground) going to Morden via Bank.

But for all other uses, *through* will do perfectly well. It sounds more fitting in our Anglo Saxon tongue and it's shorter (in terms of syllable count) so easier to say, hear and process in the brain. Look at tchrist's last set of quotes that might allow via to substitute for through: in none of them would the substitution improve the flow or clarity or aesthetics of the sentence.

Comment: Are you sure via is reserved for physical routes? The recent proliferation of via may be due to the proliferation of the written word ("via is much shorter than through") moreso than the spoken word.

Answer (score 1):

> The preposition ‘through’ is often used in sentences when something is
> going in from one side /end and coming out of another end. Example.
> The plane went through the clouds.
>
> The preposition ‘via’ is used in sentences when we are talking about a
> path that passes through. Example . to fly to America via India.
>
> Some of the examples of ‘ through’ are:-
>
> 1. The train went ‘through’ the tunnel.
> 2. The needle passes ‘through’ the cloth.
>
> Some of the examples of ‘ via’ are:-
>
> 1. We can take a solution ‘via’ injury.
> 2. Please complete the Paytm ‘via’ PatTm.

[Read More.](https://askanydifference.com/difference-between-through-and-via/)